# Calling Service in Broadcast receiver Issue

Tags: android

When i call my service in a broadcast receiver if i put at the last of onReceive method; the service got triggered correctly but if i put the call and i do some other things after the service never got triggered.

Let me explain, if i do this the service got triggered

```
public class receiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive( Context context, Intent intent ) {

        // OK
        Intent i = new Intent( context, MyService.class );
        context.startService( i );
    }
}
```

But if i do this, the service never got triggered and i need to do some other things after the service...

```
public class receiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

        @Override
        public void onReceive( Context context, Intent intent ) {
            Intent i = new Intent( context, MyService.class );
            context.startService( i );

            someMethod();
        }
    }
```

Maybe i need to add some instruction before i call the service ? .- Sorry about my english

Comment: Please check your service and code care fully. It have some other issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> But if i do this, the service never got triggered and i need to do
>   some other things after the service...

it may help you:

```
    public class receiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive( Context context, Intent intent ) {
        final Context ctx = context;
        Thread  thread = new Thread(new Runnable(){
              @Override
              public void run(){
                  Intent i = new Intent( context, MyService.class );
                  ctx.startService( i );
              }
        });

       thread.start();

       someMethod();
    }
}
```

Comment: can i use threads in a broadcastreceiver ? it seems the debugger just pass over the thread and dont execute it

Comment: yes you can and if you want to check it set the break point inside run method.